# Keras custom metric and shuffle/batching

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to implement a custom metric in Keras. However, the calculation of the metric does not only require knowledge of `y_true` and `y_pred` but it needs another sample-dependent field. Essentially, I want to perform the following calculation: `my_metric=(y_true - y_pred)^2 / p` where each sample is associated with a different `p` (each `y_true` and `y_pred` is a vector and so each `p` is a vector, too).

The problem I have is that the metric and loss functions have a signature like `my_loss_or_metric(y_true, y_pred)` and I don't know to what samples those tensors belong to (i.e., what inputs produced these). **First question**: do `y_true` and `y_pred` contain the results for all inputs at the end of an epoch or is this the data for one batch only? If it is only for one batch, how do I find which batch? **Second question**: if I let Keras shuffle the inputs I don't know how the inputs got shuffled. Is there a way to ask Keras for the permutation in the form of the used `index_array` or something? Or are `y_true` and `y_pred` in the original order without shuffling? And the important **third question**: How can I mix in the `p` vectors in my loss calculation? The Keras loss and metric functions are working "symbolically" on tensors and only produce a computation graph, therefore I can't just pass `p` in "from the side" (i.e., I can't just capture the `p` numpy array, it needs to be a tensor, right? But `p` is not an input to the NN model)

I looked in the Keras source code but I didn't see anything obvious. Also I am using the Keras that's built into TensorFlow, if that makes any difference. Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that your metric is squared error divided by a weight specific to each sample. Maybe you can provide `1 / p` as sample weights?

Comment: Good point and thanks. But sadly in reality my formula is a bit more complex and I need different p's and more arithmetic where I don't think simple weights will be enough. But if necessary I will have to approximate with something like `1/p`.